# Docker temporary files strategy

Tags: docker

My docker produces some temporary files.

Is there an encouraged strategy regarding those?

If I put those to `/tmp`, [I'm not sure](https://web.archive.org/web/20170322124844/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815963/are-default-cronjobs-executed-in-a-docker) they'll get cleared.

Or should I expose the volume `/tmp` from the host machine?

Comment: Are your containers going to be really long running? They won't be cleaned as is because there's no cron in the container (unless you explicitly set it up).

Comment: Yes, they are webservers, they are expected to be long-running. So I guess there is no best practice out-of-the-box for the moment, right?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I am not aware of any encouraged way to manage temporary files with Docker as it will mostly depend on how you need to handle these temporary files with your application (should they be deleted on restart? Periodically?...)

You have several possibilities depending on your needs:

## Use Docker [`tmpfs` mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/)

You can mount a `tmpfs` volume which will persist data as long as the container is running (i.e. the data in the volume will be deleted when the container stops), for example:

```
docker run --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/myapp/tmpdir someimage
```

This may be useful if you (can) restart your containers regularly and the temporary data may be recreated on container restart. However if you need to be able to clean up temporary data while the container is running, this is not a good solution as you will need to stop the container to have your temporary data cleaned.

*Edit: as per @alexander-azarov coment, the tmpfs volume size is unlimited by default with the risk of the container using up all the machine memory. Using [`tmpfs-size`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/#specify-tmpfs-options) flag is recommended to mitigate that risk, such as `docker run --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/app,tmpfs-size=4096`*

## Writing into the [container writable layer](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#container-and-layers)

The writable layer of the container is where all the data will be written in the container if no volume is mounted. It will persist on container restart, but will be deleted if the container is deleted.

This way the temporary data will be deleted only when the container is deleted. It may be a good solution for short-lived containers, but not for long-lived containers.

## Mounting host machine `/tmp` in the container with a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount)

For example:

```
docker run -v /tmp/myapp-tmp-dir:/myapp/tmpdir someimage
```

This will cause all data to be written in the host machine `/tmp/myapp-tmp-dir` directory, and result will depend on how the host machine manage `/tmp` (in most cases, data are cleared upon machine restart)

## [Create and mount a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume) to manage data into

You can create a volume which will contain your data, for example:

```
docker run --mount source=myappvol,target=/myapp/tmpdir someimage
```

And manage the data in the volume: mount-it in another container and cleanup the data, deleting the volume, etc.

---

These are the most common solutions relying (almost) solely on Docker functionalities. Another possibility would be to handle temporary files directly from your software or app running in the container, but it's more an application-related issue than a Docker-related one.

Comment: Thank you, personally I found your answer to be comprehensive. I have the only note that I think is worth mentioning: since a `tmpfs` mount resides in memory, there may be a risk to exhaust all the host's memory.

Comment: Good point, this can be mitigated using `tmpfs-size` flag to limit the allocated size. I'll edit accordingly, thanks for the feedback

Comment: How about mounting to `/tmp/myapp:/myapp/tmpdir` instead of `/tmp:/myapp/tmpdir`? The container will be not longer able to access the temp files of the host.

Comment: is writing in host machine /tmp the most "efficient" (if you don't use tmpfs)? trying to resolve cannotinspect container errors in AWS (which seems to be about disk usage)

Comment: Efficiency in term of IO and speed may be better using tmpfs (from my own experience), but it may eat-up all your RAM. It depends on what efficiency you're looking for

Comment: How to configure the tmpfs in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't in Dockerfile, you can only declare volumes path there, specifying that it's a `tmpfs` must happen at runtime. You can see details on https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: A note on using the container writable layer - it is easy to do and will work, but performance is generally worse than the other options.