# How to delete file in python inside docker container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

The code  below is part of my code. In my local machine, everything is fine.However, I deploy my code and inside of docker container,it gives the error ***"result": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: path"***. What could be solution to delete in docker container also? I tried `os.remove()` also,It didn't work.

```
path = "/mypath/"
output = path + "myfile.pdf"

result_file = open(output, "w+b")

pisa_res = pisa.CreatePDF(
        source_html,               
        dest = result_file)

result_file.close()  

with open(output, "rb") as pdf_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read())       

os.system(f"rm -rf {output}")
```

Comment: Check if the user that executes this code has rights to delete this file. Sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: This might help, also, I would recommend attaching a tmpfs to the container or your /tmp folder, that will be easier to manage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816048/docker-temporary-files-strategy/55104489

Comment: I don't understand why you save it in file and later read it -- can't you do it withoute file ? Eventually you can use `io.BytesIO` to create file in memory without writing on disk. And then you don't have to delete it.

Comment: @EminMastizada it is not what I want.

Comment: @Kroustou I will check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the problem with this file and how to delete it

but I would use `io.BytesIO` to create file in memory and then it doesn't create file on disk and it doesn't need to delete it

I don't have `pisa` to test it but it should be something like this

```
import io

result_file = io.BytesIO()

pisa_res = pisa.CreatePDF(
        source_html,               
        dest=result_file)

result_file.seek(0) # move to the beginning of file to read it

encoded_string = base64.b64encode(result_file.read())
```

Module `io` is standard module so you don't have to install it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. This is better way to implement.